# css3 columns and overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to use css columns to make a pinterest style layout. It's working, but the elements in the columns have a diagonal ribbon over the top corner that uses `overflow: hidden`. These ribbons only show up on the elements of the *first* column. I'd expect them to show up on all elements in every column. If you remove the `overflow: hidden` the ribbons appear on all elements. I've made a jsfiddle to demonstrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/6ooefvq3/5/

This behaviour only seems to occur in chrome on mac (49.0.2592.0 canary), it looks ok on safari (9.0.2).

Any idea what I may be missing, or need to change, so these ribbons show up on all elements in all columns?

**EDIT**

[image: Screenshot of jsfiddle with red ribbons in first column, and no ribbons in second column]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I see only one column of elements in the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, maybe the fiddle needs to be a certain width. As @max requested, i updated the question with a screenshot of the fiddle.

Comment: Why not just do it the old fashion way? https://jsfiddle.net/6ooefvq3/6/

Comment: I have spent a good 30 minutes messing with positioning and dimensions, but the issue might as well be a Chrome bug on OS X. As Adam said, you will have to use a different column system for now.

Comment: I tried to replace overflow:hidden with   clip: rect(0,20px,20px,0);  and the issue is still there. Also with   clip: rect(0,2000px,2000px,0); ...

Comment: Thanks for the time, everybody. @adam, I guess when I said "pinterest style" I meant "these elements won't have the same height, so there would be gaps left over if i float them (as per [this tutorial](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout))". The fiddle was just the smallest example I could give of the problem, though a little misleading that way. But I think ye are right and I may have to change column system for now. I've reported it as a bug in chrome just in case.

Comment: Just for information: On Chrome for Windows 10 I can reproduce this problem as well.

Comment: maybe use a .SVG as the ribon instead?

Comment: Good luck! I've been messing around with this for quite a while now and to no avail, can't figure it out for the life of me. Weird little bug.

Comment: It's a known bug with `transform` and `overflow` in Webkit-based browsers - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687023/bug-with-transform-scale-and-overflow-hidden-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with the transform property on the ribbon and the fact that it is positioned relatively... but the behavior is too strange for me to make sense of. It may be related to, or be similar to the [fixed position bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2637058/2126792) that has been reported many times.

---

I have come up with the following work-around using borders instead of an overflow-clipped div:

First move the transforms to the div with `overflow: hidden;` and remove `position: relative;` from the ribbon. You should then see all the ribbons.

Second remove the background and padding from the ribbon and add borders like so:

```
border-bottom: 6px solid red;
border-top: 6px solid transparent;
border-left: 6px solid transparent;
border-right: 6px solid transparent;
```

Finally all you have to do is position and size the wrapper. You could also remove `overflow: hidden;`, but because you have a shadow on the ribbon I would leave it in.

[Here is your adjusted jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tp40qrrg/1/) that seems to be working (at least for me). :-)

And a Snippet for good measure:

```css
.columns {
  -webkit-column-width: 250px;
  column-width: 250px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 440px;
}

body {
background: #ccc;
}

.box {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.ribbon-wrapper {
  width: 32px;
  height: 12px;
  overflow: hidden; /* remove this and the ribbons appear */     
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
}

.ribbon {
  font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-bottom: 6px solid red;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
   <div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper">
      <div class="ribbon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper">
      <div class="ribbon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper">
      <div class="ribbon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper">
      <div class="ribbon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper">
      <div class="ribbon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper">
      <div class="ribbon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a crazy but useable workaround, thanks! Looks good in Chrome for me so I'll mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity

```
/*
 __     __   __   __                ___       __   ___  __      ___  __   __     
|__) | |__) |__) /  \ |\ |    |__| |__  |    |__) |__  |__)    |__  /  \ |__)
|  \ | |__) |__) \__/ | \|    |  | |___ |___ |    |___ |  \    |    \__/ |  \
 ___  __   __       ___  ___       __      __             
|__  |__) /  \ |\ |  |  |__  |\ | |  \    |__)  /\  | |\ |
|    |  \ \__/ | \|  |  |___ | \| |__/    |    /~~\ | | \| 
*/


@mixin HELPER-ribbon($width:130px,$thickness:35px,$shadow:0,$font:10px,$font-color:#000,$color:gold) {
& {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
user-select: none;
pointer-events: none;
width:$width+(($thickness*1.41)/2*(-1)); //1.41 ~ √2
height: $width+(($thickness*1.41)/2*(-1));
overflow: hidden;
color:$font-color;

&:before { 
  @if($shadow==1){
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 7px rgba(#000,0.1));
    //box-shadow:0px 0px 7px rgba(#000,0.1);
  }
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  right:($width - ($width/1.41))*(-1);
  top: 0px; 
  margin-top:(($thickness*1.41)/2*(-1));
  margin-right:(($thickness*1.41)/2*(-1));
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-bottom:-($thickness*0.5);
  border-bottom: $thickness solid $color;
  border-left: $thickness solid transparent;
  border-right: $thickness solid transparent;
  height: 0px;
  width: $width;
  line-height:$thickness - 2px; 
}
&:after {
  content:attr(title);
  font-weight:500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: $font;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  line-height:$thickness - 2px; 
  position: absolute;
  right:($width - ($width/1.41))*(-1);
  top: 0px; 
  margin-top:(($thickness*1.41)/2*(-1));
  margin-right:(($thickness*1.41)/2*(-1));
  width: $width;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:2;
}
}
}
.ribbon {
  width:100%; @include HELPER-ribbon($width: 150px, $thickness:20px, $shadow:1)
}
```

https://pp98rx64q0.codesandbox.io/