# CSS opacity transition ignoring overflow:hidden in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, opacity, transition

Having an issue with CSS transitions ignoring their parents overflow property during the transition in Chrome/Safari.

JS adding an active class to the child:

```
$('.child').addClass('active');
```

CSS for the parent/child

```
.parent {
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background:#000;
  border-radius:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.child {
  opacity:0;
  transition:1s opacity ease-in-out;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  background:blue;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;

  &.active {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ejm7qr/1/

During the transition, the child's content is shown outside of it's parent then disappears on completion.

Have tried adding backface-visibility with no luck.

Been trying to find the same problem but haven't had any luck... Was wondering if this is a known issue in Chrome/Safari and whether there's a fix / workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have 3 solutions to your problem.

The two solutions that have already been stated as:

1. Add `z-index: 1` to your parent.
2. Mention `border-radius: 50%` to the child.

And,

3. Just add the `backface-visibility` browser specific properties to your parent, along with the `transform: translate3d` properties. You have to set the `translate3d` properties manually due to a bug in the webkit browsers.

   ```
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   ```

Comment: Ah I didn't realise  I needed the translate3d as well, thank you.

Comment: This solution didn't work for my problem (iOS 14.6), I had to wrap the child with another div and that div also has overflow hidden. Example: `<div class="parent" style="overflow:hidden"><div class="wrapper" style="overflow:hidden"><div class="animation"></div></div></div>`

Answer (score 1):

It can be browser bug . But you can give `border-radius: 50%` for your child element . After giving radius for child everything will for in all browsers

Comment: This wouldn't work for what I'm actually creating as the image inside the parent can be any size meaning it wouldn't work on very wide/tall images. thanks though

Comment: and what if you use image in background with `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 1):

I added `z-index` to both elements, and maybe is what are you looking at. https://jsfiddle.net/b3ejm7qr/2/

If not, looks like is a bug type, as Giorgi says ([Google search](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20transitions%20parent%20overflow), [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687023/bug-with-transform-scale-and-overflow-hidden-in-chrome)).

Comment: I honestly had searched multiple variants of your search with no luck... think i'm not so good at googling :) thanks!