# HTML5 video controls on Android Chrome don't span full width of video in this simple page

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, html5-video

Save this as an html file and load it up in Android Chrome:

```
<html>
<body style="overflow:hidden;transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);">
        <video controls>
            <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
        </video>
</body>
</html>
```

It should look like this:

[image]

If you play around with it, you'll find that removing EITHER the `overflow:hidden` or the `transform:scale` will make the controls span the whole width of the video as expected. However the combination of these two styles makes any video controls incorrectly sized, as shown.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687023/bug-with-transform-scale-and-overflow-hidden-in-chrome) seems somewhat related and suggests adding a `transform: translateZ(0)` to the containing element, however adding that translation either to the existing transform on the body or onto a new containing div does not resolve the issue.

Is this a bug in Android Chrome? I don't understand why the conjunction of these two styles should affect video control width.

Comment: Does adding a viewport help? It's possible that the browser is inventing a different viewport size in each case.

Comment: is the behavior as a expected in other browsers/devices?

Comment: @JoshLee - adding a viewport does not help unfortunately. Adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in a `<head>` has no effect.

@mad.meesh - It is. On any desktop browser, the video controls span the full width of the video. Same on my iPhone 6 plus. Same on Android Firefox. This appears to be limited to Android Chrome.

Comment: the problem is the video controls that are not being scaled by the transform? I have tested on an full HD phone and it works ok...

Comment: I have run into a similar issue but it was due to a `<video>` element set to `width: 100%` inside of a Bootstrap carousel. If I resize the browser window or click on the 'Play' control it corrects itself (must tickle the rendering engine or something)

Answer (score 1):

To change the width of the video player's native controls bar you can add following in the css:

```
  video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Here is the good [example](https://codepen.io/BainjaminLafalize/pen/GiJwn)  of styling native controls. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the tag to something like this

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting width and height in a non-standard way, though there may legitimately be a bug, but it seems you are setting the width of the video to be half of it's native width. I recommend you set your style to be:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

video {
  display: inline;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Some Video</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls></video>
  </body>
</html>
```